# How to open model from ts file of angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-bootstrap, ngoninit

I try to open the model on my page is load

HTML

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Hi there!</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" [hidden]="true" (click)="open(content)" data-target="#varify_warning">Launch demo modal</button>
```

TS file

```
ngOnInit(): void 
  {
    document.getElementById("varify_warning")?.click();
  }
```

But the model didn't open?

**I want to trigger the click() event on the Launch demo modal button from ngInit()**

Comment: Are you using `ngbModal`?

Comment: yes..! import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Comment: Okay, it's easy. I'll answer right away.

Comment: Yes, I know it is easy but something is wrong with my code and I don't know what it was..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Open ngbModal on button click

On your `.ts` file, add this:

```
  open(content: any) {
    this.modalService.open(content);
  }
```

And in your `.html` file, add this:

```
    <button (click)="open(content)">Open modal</button>
    <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
       modal content goes here
    </ng-template>
```

### Open ngbModal on ngOnInit

On your `.ts` file, add this:

```
        @ViewChild("content",{static:true}) content:ElementRef;
        ngOnInit(): void {
            this.modalService.open(this.content);
        }
```

And in your `.html` file, add this:

```
    <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
       modal content goes here
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: No this is not what i want..! I already did that

Comment: I want to open my model automatically without clicking on any button

Comment: But that's how you should open your moda, from `ngbModal`..

Comment: I want to trigger click() event on Launch demo modal button from ngInit()

Comment: Hey @Amol_G, I edited it, I hope this works now!